# Problems initializing a final variable in my second constructor

Tags: java, final

I'm trying to use 2 constructors in my class by using the first constructor to set up my second constructor but doing that I get the error, that "The blank final field VALUE might not have been initialized" even though I don´t get an error in my first constructor. Here's my code:

```
public class Token implements IToken {

    private static int counter = 0;
    private final int ID;
    private TokenState state;
    private final int VALUE;
    private org.newdawn.slick.geom.Vector2f pos;


    public Token (TokenState state, int value, Vector2f pos ) {
        ID = counter;
        this.VALUE = value;
        this.state = state;
        this.pos = pos;
        counter++ ;
    }


    public Token (int value) {

        new Token(TokenState.DEFAULT, value, new Vector2f() );
        ID = counter;
        counter++;
    }
```

Does the problem lies with the fact that it's a final variable. If yes then why?

Comment: You need to call `this (TokenState.DEFAULT, value, new Vector2f()) ` as the first call, not `new Token (...) `. That just creates a new Token and throws it away immediately.

Comment: And you then need to remove the other two statements in the second constructor.

Comment: Also, `ID = counter;` followed by `counter++;` is a multithreading issue just waiting to bite somebody in the backside.  Look at `AtomicInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

> using reference variable keyword "this" as below

```
public Token (int value) {
 this(TokenState.DEFAULT, value, new Vector2f() );    

    }
```

another problem you've face "ID" variable declared as "final" that's mean cannot be initialized in two different area you might 
remove final keyword or initialize it once.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Was confused thinking there was a problem with final variable. I fixed the mistake with the initializing the final variable in 2 different areas right after posting this but thanks for explaining.